# Microsoft CA Auto Enrollment

Tags: pki

If, Do not automatically enroll checkbox is ticked, what will happen if a certificate gets expired?

Does "renewal period" will conflict with "do not auto reenroll"?

When a cert is going to expire, a new one will be issued when only 6 weeks are remaining till expiry...but "do not auto reenroll" should block it from getting issued because it will be duplicate certificate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a certificate in AD expires, the client will re-enrol.  The checkbox simply stops multiple devices re-enrolling on behalf of the user if a *valid* certificate is in AD.

When un-ticked and a user moves from one device to another, they would enrol for a certificate at each device which would be stored in AD.  AD would therefore grow considerably.

When a client renews a certificate (at some point up to 6 weeks before expiry in your case), the old certificate is archived.  The above is only relevant in the period up to the 6 week renewal period.

Comment: what will happen if the cert is deleted from user's personal store and this option is ticked.....I have just entered the IT Industry....Thank you for the help

Comment: I can't say that I've tried it.  Give it a go in a lab environment - it's what they're there for.  If I had to guess, I'd say it would wait until renewal time before requesting another cert.

Comment: It didn't work, but how is it different from logging in from a new pc. In both cases (1. Delete cert from personal store and then try to login 2.Login from a different PC ) should get a cert from AD. Can you please explain this behavior

Comment: If the certificate is in AD you will not get a replacement when this checkbox is ticked.  Deleting from the Personal store doesn't delete it from AD as far as I know.  You can view the user with ADSIEdit to confirm this.  If the certificate still exists in AD, delete it, and see if that allows the user to re-enroll.

Comment: alright...one more thing Gareth, When a user logins to different PC, he will get his cert from AD but he still won't have the private key. So does that user will get issues on the new PC? How will the user be able to decrypt the received messages without private key?

Comment: The certificate in AD allows others to find your public key, so that they can for example, encrypt a message to you.  If you want your private key and certificate to move with you when you log in to different machines, you need to use _Credential Roaming_.